# Removing lines in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I'm editing a long list of 5 numbers in Notepad but need to remove every line that begins with 2. How do I do this? Example list below...

1 9 11 18 29

2 9 11 18 29

3 9 11 18 29

4 9 11 18 29

5 9 11 18 29

6 9 11 18 29

1 2 12 18 29

2 3 12 18 29

2 4 12 18 29

1 5 12 18 29

Comment: I am not 100% but if Notepad++ has a regular expression search this worked for me using sublime text ^2(.*) to find the lines then replace with nothing.

Comment: Ok I did that but it removes lines that begin with 21,22,23,etc. also.

Comment: In that case the correct answer is below, much better info on removing the blank lines in notepad++ too! Just make sure you definitely put the space after the number 2 and before the opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Find `^2 (.*)$` and replace with nothing.  This will replace each list of five numbers starting with a `2` with a blank line.

Alternatively, you can go to the Mark tab on the Search dialog, Bookmark the lines that match the pattern above, then Search > Bookmark > Remove Bookmarked Lines.  This will completely remove lines that start with `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Notepad++ regex Find-and-Replace:

Find what:

```
^2[\s\S]+?^(?=\d)
```

Replace it with nothing.