# Removing sequences in Notepad

Tags: notepad++

Using Notepad++, how do I remove all lines with a 1,2 sequence? Example list below...

1 2 3 8 9

1 3 4 8 9

2 3 4 8 9

1 2 5 8 9

1 3 5 8 9

2 3 5 8 9

1 2 6 8 9

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing lines in Notepad ++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578152/removing-lines-in-notepad)

Comment: You might want to use regex. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918158/how-to-delete-specific-lines-on-notepad).

Answer (score 2):

enable regexes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> for this:

`^1 2 (.*)$`

replace with nothing, and click replace all.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17579942/2502012), tested on my n++, works fine.

**edit** see comment if you want to remove linebreaks

Comment: +1 this is it. And if the OP wants to remove the line breaks also, then `^1 2 (.*)$\r?\n?` would suffice. Cheers.

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't recognize `\n` in regexp mode.